# How can I add application resources to my C# backend for the application instead of in the XAML file?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my XAML file I have this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:M">
    <Application.Resources>
        <converters:InverseBool x:Key="InverseBool" />
        <Color x:Key="IconAsphalt">#34495E</Color>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To do the same in C# I am thinking I can do something like this but I realize I am missing somethings. Can someone who knows how to do this tell me what is needed?

```
public App()
{
    Resources.Add("InverseBool", "InverseBool");
```

I don't know for example how to specify the namespace for `InverseBool`.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: The namespace shouldn't be that hard, the same like the namespaces in top of your .cs files that follows keyword `using`

Comment: Yes, but how do I add that as there's a string as the first parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply use [Resources.Add(string key, object value)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.resourcedictionary.add?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ResourceDictionary_Add_System_String_System_Object_)

```
Resources.Add("InverseBool", new InverseBool());
```

of course you need to include the namespace where your `InverseBool` class is defined.