# Is it possible to bind value for FontSize from a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on an app where I am in need of changeing the text size from small to big with help of a settings page.

I have decoupled my code from the app.xaml and added some references there instread from some ResourceDictionary i've created.

I am now wondering if its possible to bind the value.

```
    <Style x:Key="articleBodyText" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding SelectedFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,15"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Light={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the ResourceDictionary ?

Comment: Define a double property "SelectedFontSize" and you can do it.

Comment: @Shaw I posted a similar answer earlier but according to OP wasn't the correct answer " Is it possible bind property of a viewmodel to a resource Dictionary?" which is not clear imho

Comment: @Cfun I see, then probably define different sizes in a resource Dictionary and choose one in SettingViewModel, a bit complex to bind in resource dict.

Answer (score 1):

Define a property of type double

```
    private double _SelectedFontSize;
    public double SelectedFontSize
        {
            get => _SelectedFontSize;
            set => SetProperty(ref _SelectedFontSize, value);  //INotifyProertyChanged
        }
```

Supposed you have defined `CustomSmall` resource either in xaml or in code:

```
    Resources.Add("CustomSmall", 10);
    Resources.Add("CustomLarge", 22);
```

```
    Resources.TryGetValue("CustomSmall", out var fontSize);
    FontSize = (double)fontSize;
```

Related question

[How can I add application resources to my C# backend for the application instead of in the XAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980252/how-can-i-add-application-resources-to-my-c-sharp-backend-for-the-application-in/65980570#65980570)

Comment: GetNamedSize is something i can use but it does not answer my question. Is it possible bind property of a viewmodel to a resource Dictionary?

Comment: The answer is not really what I was looking for, what you displayed is the binding you do in MVVM. Want I asked for is if its possible to databinding in a DictionaryResource I wished to use a specific font property for that.

Comment: Using Binding doesn't mean it follows MVVM, you cannot use Binding in ResourceDictionary https://stackoverflow.com/q/37396964

Answer (score 0):

Value=new Binding(16) for example should set the Fontsize to 16. So you pass the chosen value from you're settings Page and use it in the binding.

Comment: How would that "new binding()" be dynamic? if you write the number within the "()".

Comment: It was just An example. I suppose you can pass the value that they user entered on the settings page and use this value in the binding?